# Enable network simulation doesn't work for query IsNetworkAvailable

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to find out in my app is there network available using Tools/Simulation Dashboard in Visual Studio 2012 for WP 8 app (of course, debug mode is on).
Whatever I do I got for DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable always true although I set Control setting to No Network. But if I try some activity in app that need network access I can't do that (so it works but withoud detection which is my primary goal).
Are they any thing to do to get False to my query and to do i.e. Message Box that says "No Network available".

Also, 
DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator
always return Fake GSM Network" with No Network setting set to. When I change setting I got "Simulation setting were applied succesfully" in VS status bar.

[image: simulation dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. I will answer based on the fact that I designed this feature as a Program Manager in Microsoft.

Simulation Dashboard currently only throttles the Network Bandwidth (limited by your current network) and do not simulate "actual" network conditions. So APIs will still return the "actual" network type and/or name but the network speed/quality will be affected as per your choice when the Network Simulation is enabled. In case you want to validate the API calls, you might have to test your app on a Windows Phone device with data connection switched off.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your answer. I was just curious why if I choose No Network (with Enable Network Simulation checked) Simulation Dashboard don't turn data connection?

Comment: Rahul, before i start moaning on Twitter I wanted to ask you direct. (thanks for coming on here btw) Why does it throttle rather than simulate a dropped connection? Switching back and forth to Flight mode or turning off Data connection is a bit pants