# detect active network connection

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anyone suggest a reliable way of detecting the current network status and type for WP7.

I'm using the Simulation Dashboard in Visual Studio 2012 to test my app under various network scenarios. I know it's working because my app won't connect when there is no network or will download very slowly when network speed is set to 2G etc.

However

```
    NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

always returns true, whatever the network speed setting, and

```
    NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType
```

always returns NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211, whatever the current network settings.

Comment: You can see it..http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-14.html

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered at [Enable network simulation doesn't work for query IsNetworkAvailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066532/enable-network-simulation-doesnt-work-for-query-isnetworkavailable/14404764#14404764)

Simulation Dashboard currently only throttles the Network Bandwidth (limited by your current network) and do not simulate "actual" network conditions. So APIs will still return the "actual" network type and/or name but the network speed/quality will be affected as per your choice when the Network Simulation is enabled. In case you want to validate the API calls, you might have to test your app on a Windows Phone device with data connection altered appropriately.